# Get git clone directory without cloning or creating dir

Tags: git, directory, git-clone

I'd like to get the name of directory that Git would create

For example, these commands would each create a `Hello-World` dir and clone into that:

```
git clone http://github.com/octocat/Hello-World
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git
```

I'd like get the value `Hello-World` for processing before any directory is created or any files are cloned.

Is it possible to do this using Git?

Or do I need to manually preprocess the clone URL to find the part after the last `/` and chop off any `.git`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
$ basename https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World .git
Hello-World

$ basename https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git .git
Hello-World
```

Comment: Thanks, also works for the case I forgot with a trailing slash: `basename https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/ .git` -> `Hello-World`